# Set file creation date to its modification date on OSX

Tags: files, osx, timestamps, touch

I need to batch edit file creation date (some stupid audio recorder set the file creation date to UNIX epoch and the correct recording date in the modification date) to set it to the files modification date.

I am aware of the `touch` command which can set a file creation like this `touch -t 201406251546.10 filename.wav` but I don't know how to retrieve each file modification date to give it as an argument to the `touch` command.

I also know that the `ls -lT` command prints the modification time before each file but on my system (OS X 10.9) the output is localized which is not really handy for batch processing

Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I found a way around my particular problem thanks to [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/99599/53984). It is MacOS only though.

```
SetFile -d "$(GetFileInfo -m filename.wav)" filename.wav
```

Comment: Since other flavors of Unix don't have file creation dates, it makes sense that the solution would be OSX-only.